# Web2py server problem

Tags: connection, request, wait, web2py

I am running a web2py server which handles some requests which may take a total completion time of few seconds to few minutes. Once a connection is made to the server and it is processing a request which takes about 2-3 minutes, new connections to the server have to wait untill the former's request is completed.

I don't know if we can tweak some parameters in web2py for this. Do we have any way out of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

web2py does not lock the server when busy with a connection but it does lock the user session, on purpose. That means other users can connect but not the one that started the original request. In the acton that takes time you can do:

session._unlock(response)

and this problem (if diagnosis is correct) will go away.

Anyway, it is not a good idea to have requests that take so long. The web server may kill your process and it is not good for usability. You should have a db table where you queue such tasks and handle them in a background process (explained in the manual) than use ajax or html5 websockets (web2y/gluon/contrib/comet_messaging.py) to check progress on the long running task.

Please bring this up on the web2py mailing list and we will help with more concrete examples.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.
session._unlock(response) worked nicely
I tried finding out the file comet_messaging.py but couldn't. If you could help me finding this file and using it further.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the use of html5?

Comment: Note, you can also call `session.forget(response)`, which will unlock the session file and also close it (and make sure the session is not written to it).

Comment: You can find comet_messaging.py [here](http://code.google.com/p/web2py/source/browse/gluon/contrib/comet_messaging.py). In the source code, it's in /web2py/gluon/contrib/.